# Sharing a QGIS project with geotagged images

Tags: qgis, geotag

I have a QGIS project file with geotagged images. Is there a simple way to share this with a client?

We have come up with two possible solutions so far, which are not great:

1. Prepare a QGIS project with relative paths. Zip all the files (shapefiles, qgs file etc) and send it to the client. Instruct the client on how to download and install QGIS in order to view map with images.
2. Create KML/KMZ files so the client can use Google Earth to view the geotagged images.

Comment: QGIS server may be a third option, but the client must have an internet connection and you must set up a server.

Comment: Have you looked at the qgis2web plugin?

Answer (score 1):

It is now possible to solve this using QGIS Cloud.

Comment: And just how would that be accomplished?